# Sefas Emes and your mission

Tags: sources-mekorot, books-generally, mussar-ethics, commentaries, pirke-avot-ethicsof

Someone mentioned that the Sefas Emes quotes in the name of the Chiddushei HaRim on that Mishnah  (Avos 1:14), אם אין אני לי מי לי, וכשאני לעצמי מה אני, ואם... The Sefas Emes says, Every yid has something that only HE can fix! That your mission and our job.

Does anyone know the source of where the Sefas Emes is located?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is found in the commentary of the [*S'fas Emes* on *Avos* 4:2](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=5311&st=&pgnum=66):

> אא"ז ז"ל פי'… ע"פ המשנה אם אין אני לי כו' שיש לכל איש ישראל דבר מיוחד שאין אחר יכול לתקנו רק הוא וכמו כן לכל שעה דבר מיוחד שא"י לתקנו רק בשעה זו...

English:

> My [grandfather](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yitzchak_Meir_Alter) gave an explanation of the midrash on *B'chukosai*<sup>1</sup> ([ויקרא רבה לה:א](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%95%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%90_%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%94_%D7%9C%D7%94_%D7%90)), in accordance with the mishna, "If I am not for myself, who will be for me" (*Avos* 1:14), that every Jewish person has a particular task that can only be accomplished by him. Likewise, every hour has something particular that can only be accomplished in that hour...

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>'[I planned my ways, but [lit. and] I turned my feet to your testimonies](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt26b9.htm#59)': David said, 'Master of the universe, every day I would plan to go to some particular destination or to some particular domicile, but my feet would take me to synagogues and study halls!'</sub>